# Access Huawei E3131 on a headless debian based linux system

Tags: usb, debian, ethernet, dongle

I tried to access the Huawei E3131 on a headless debian system but the network interface was not avayable. The question is, how to access it?

---

*[There is a follow up question for sending / receiving sms on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38016641/6509463)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several things, not sure which of these are really necessary and which not...

So this answer is a solution if there is already a network connection and the E3131 is **not** used for acessing the network or internet.

---

Static IP for E3131 (eth1 in my case):

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

My content is the following:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
metric 0

# E3131
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.8.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.8.1 # With a new installation this line added a second default gateway which I dont wanted. So maybe you should remove this line.
metric 1
```

---

Maybe it helps to use metrics, but really not sure. To use this (see content above) the following needs to be installed:

```
sudo aptitude install ifmetric
```

---

For assigning the right interfaces to eth0 and eth1 I did the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

And:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/010_netinterfaces.rules
```

Content:

```
KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", NAME="eth0"
KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY", NAME="eth1"
```

"XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" is the hardware address of the original network interface.

"YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY" is the hardware address of the E3131.

---

If the E3131 is not recognized as a network interface but as cdrom, then this can be changed by:

```
sudo /usr/bin/sg_raw /dev/sr0 11 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
```

For this the following is needed:

```
sudo apt-get install sg3-utils
```

---

I also installed the network-manager. Not really sure if this is necessary:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install network-manager
```